# Arduino IDE doesn't find sys/time.h in Windows

Tags: c, azure, arduino, iot

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/iot-hub-c-m0wifi-getstartedkit/) to start testing my new Adafruit Azure IoT starter Kit that comes with an Arduino Feather M0 Wifi. I was able to setup the Arduino IDE 1.8.4 (From Windows Store) on my PC which is a Windows 10. In the step 1.8 (Build Your Remote Monitoring Sample), when I try to compile the solution "remote_monitoring.ino" dowonload from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-c-m0wifi-getstartedkit/archive/master.zip), it appears the following error:

> C:\iot-hub-c-m0wifi-getstartedkit-master\remote_monitoring\remote_monitoring.ino:12:22:
>   fatal error: sys/time.h: No such file or directory
>
> `#include <sys/time.h>`
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

It seems like in Windows, including sys/time.h just doesn't Works, but if I try to delete the sys/ part, it comes the following error:

> C:\Users\jonguz\OneDrive -
>   Microsoft\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/sdk/serializer.h:42:19:
>   fatal error: cstdlib: No such file or directory
>
> `#include <cstdlib>`

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Which board do you have selected from the **Tools > Board** menu?

Comment: Thanks for your tip!, it was exactly that, I have not choose the board! :-)

Comment: Glad it's working for you now! I have written an answer just so this question can have an official resolution instead of only some comments.

Answer (score 0):

sys/time.h and cstdlib are located in the toolchain used by the Adafruit SAMD Boards hardware package (specifically arm-none-eabi-gcc). The files in this tool are only added to the include search path when a board that uses that tool is selected in the **Tools > Board** menu. If you don't have one of those boards selected then the file will not be found, thus the error messages you encountered.

From https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-wifi-atwinc1500/using-with-arduino-ide:

> Select the matching board, the current options are:
>
> - Feather M0 (for use with any Feather M0 other than the Express)

So the solution is to select Tools > Board > Adafruit Feather M0 after installing Adafruit SAMD Boards via Boards Manager but before compiling the sketch.

Answer (score 0):

one can find a header-only Windows implementation of the <sys/time.h> header on GitHub here:

https://github.com/win32ports/sys_time_h

side note: RTC time implementations for the ESP32 can be found here:

https://github.com/kerikun11/ESP32Time

and here:

https://github.com/fbiego/ESP32Time